# How to create Accelerate - Linear - Decelerate animation effect in android using ValueAnimator?

Tags: android, animation

Now I have to create an animation of a spinning fan. When user click POWER ON button, this fan begin to spin, then keep it's spinning speed at some level.When user click POWER OFF button, it slowing down then it stop.

I make some code as follows：

```
ImageView mFanImageview;
private ValueAnimator mFanValueAnimator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_centripetal_particle);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

private void startFan() {
    mFanValueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    mFanValueAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    mFanValueAnimator.setFloatValues(mFanImageview.getRotation(), mFanImageview.getRotation() + 360);
    mFanValueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    mFanValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            mFanImageview.setRotation((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    mFanValueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mFanValueAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
            mFanValueAnimator.setDuration(500);
            mFanValueAnimator.setFloatValues(mFanImageview.getRotation(), mFanImageview.getRotation() + 360);
            mFanValueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
            mFanValueAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
            mFanValueAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            mFanValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    mFanImageview.setRotation((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
            mFanValueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    stopFanValueAnimator().start();
                }
            });
            mFanValueAnimator.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            stopFanValueAnimator().start();
        }
    });
    mFanValueAnimator.start();
}

private ValueAnimator stopFanValueAnimator() {
    ValueAnimator stopAnimator = new ValueAnimator();
    stopAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    stopAnimator.setFloatValues(mFanImageview.getRotation(), mFanImageview.getRotation() + 360);
    stopAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    stopAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            mFanImageview.setRotation((Float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    return stopAnimator;
}

@OnClick(R.id.stop_button)
public void onStopButtonClicked() {
    mFanValueAnimator.cancel();
}

@OnClick(R.id.start_button)
public void onStartButtonClicked() {
    startFan();
}
```

The animation above seems ok, but I found that the fan spinning speed at the end of AccelerateInterpolator animator is hard to match the beginning of LinearInterpolator.I have to adjust duration of LinearInterpolator animator carefully.

How can I get the update rate at the end of AccelerateInterpolator animator then set the right duration of LinearInterpolator animator?

Comment: if you want such an infinite abimation use `TimeAnimator`: "This class provides a simple callback mechanism to listeners that is synchronized with all other animators in the system. There is no duration, interpolation, or object value-setting with this "

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is set accelerate interpolator initially, and on repeat again set LinearInterpolator. Now in case of repeat put a flag for handling switch off. If the switch off demanded then change value of switch Off flag that will apply Decelerate interpolator and make sure that the animation will not run again.

```
mFanValueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                if (switchOff) {
                    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                } else {
                    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It still have to set duration of animator to match the speed from accelerate to linear.